# Get drop down list default selected item is not passing to the controller in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem when the user (Edit the event) it **display drop down list for time**, and text box for date.

But **when the user submit the form the, edit action is not receiving the old value for time.**
This code works fine if the user changes the time value, it will get the value. otherwise. it wont.

**Please help me.**

****the code****

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.StartTime, Model.Times,
Model.Appointment.StartDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"), new {@class = "dropdownlist" })

public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0){
    Appointment app = eventService.GetEventByID(id);
   EventViewModel model = new EventViewModel() 
    { Appointment =app,
     StartTime = app.StartDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"),
      EndTime = app.EndDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"),
      Times = TimesSelectListItem, };

// Get the time portion of our date/time from our drop down lists
   DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(model.StartTime);
   DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(model.EndTime);

 // Create a new date based on the date from our date picker, and time from our drop down lists:
model.Appointment.StartDate = new DateTime(model.Appointment.StartDate.Year, model.Appointment.StartDate.Month, model.Appointment.StartDate.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
model.Appointment.EndDate = new DateTime(model.Appointment.EndDate.Year, model.Appointment.EndDate.Month, model.Appointment.EndDate.Day, endTime.Hour, endTime.Minute, endTime.Second);

 if (model == null)   {
  return HttpNotFound();   }

PopulatePriorityDropDownList(model.Appointment.FK_PriorityID);
 PopulatePrivacyDropDownList(model.Appointment.FK_PrivacyID);
PopulateTypeDropDownList(model.Appointment.FK_AppointmentTypeID);
       return View(model);
  }


   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Edit(EventViewModel model, int id, string PriorityID, string PrivacyID, string TypeID)
            {
//------------
this is in the controler...
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimesSelectListItem = new[] {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="6:00 AM", Value = "6:00 AM" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="6:30 AM", Value = "6:30 AM" },....etc}
```

StartTime/ StartTime : string, only to display in the view. 
StartDate/ EndDate: dateTime type from db.

Comment: Is the initial value of `StartTime` actually one of the values in your `SelectList` (for example "6:30 AM")?, and if `StartTime` has a value, why are you setting the option label (3rd parameter)?

Comment: Yes it is, I make a break point and saw that the StartTime value is filled in (Edit=Get). but when it come to the view, it is empty ! :/

Comment: Is it binding to the correct value in the dropdown - if say its "6:30 AM", is "6:30 AM" displaying in the dropdown when the page loads?

Comment: No it is not, that's why i put the optional label Model.Appointment.StartDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"),

Comment: Read my first comment again. If the value of `StartTime` is not one of the values in the `SelectList` (which it cant be otherwise it would be selected) then because you add the option label, the value on postback will be null.

Comment: as @StephenMuecke suggested, just check if app.StartDate.ToString("hh:mm tt") exists in TimesSelectListItem and if not then add a select list item before creating event view model. that should fix this issue.

Comment: Thank u Mr.Muecke, you open my eyes to the time format. I figure out that i misspelled the format 06:00. Thank you very much !

Comment: @HanoufD., If you always set the value of `StartTime`, then remove the 3rd parameter in `DropDownListFor` - its not necessary and is confusing since you are showing a time which users may think is valid. If you do leave it in then it should be something like "Please select a time"

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just did, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of `StartTime` does not match one of the properties in the `SelectList` then the value of the select will be null on postback because you have used an option label in `DropDownListFor()` (this renders an option with no value).

Check that the value of `StartTime` exactly matches the value of one of the options.

If you always set the initial value then remove the 3 parameter of the `DropDownListFor()` method

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.StartTime, Model.Times, new {@class = "dropdownlist" })
```

otherwise, make it a user friendly message so its clear that the user should select something

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.StartTime, Model.Times, "Please select a time"), new {@class = "dropdownlist" })
```